# paypal text overlapping issue in swift and ios 12 , 13 paypal / PayPal-iOS-SDK Archived

Tags: swift, user-interface, paypal

I am using paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK in swift 4.2, I am getting one text overlapping issue in SDK, 
I don't know how to solve this issue, here I attached my screenshot please check 
[image]

Here is my code

```
payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = true
                payPalConfig.merchantName = 
 payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = 
 payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = 
payPalConfig.languageOrLocale  = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = .none;

  let item1 = PayPalItem(name: "", withQuantity: 1, withPrice: NSDecimalNumber(string: String(paymentValue)), withCurrency: "", withSku: "BREWIT-0091")
            let items = [item1]
        let subtotal = PayPalItem.totalPrice(forItems: items) //This is the total price of all the items

        // Optional: include payment details
        let shipping = NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.00")
        let tax = NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.00")
        let paymentDetails = PayPalPaymentDetails(subtotal: subtotal, withShipping: shipping, withTax: tax)

        let total = subtotal.adding(shipping).adding(tax) //This is the total price including shipping and tax

        let payment = PayPalPayment(amount: total, currencyCode: "EUR", shortDescription: desctiptionOFpayment, intent: .sale)

        payment.items = items
        payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails

        if (payment.processable) {
            let paymentViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment, configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)
            present(paymentViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
            // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
            // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
            // to handle that here.
            print("Payment not processalbe: \(payment)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That SDK is deprecated and unsupported.

If you need a supported native SDK for PayPal payments, use https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/